# How to make the smart box in SQL server appear when typing?

Tags: sql-server

I am working on SQL Server for the next few weeks and am wondering how to turn on the smart box that has a list of the keywords that can be shown. For some reason the version that I am using does not show this by default, I would guess.

The code below is an example of what I am speaking of. When I typed primary key there is a list of other options, such as, check, primary, foreign, etc. I also have noticed that when I add tables to my database that they will not show in the drop down list either.

Question: is there a way to turn this on and refresh the list in the smart window?

SQL statement:

```
create table PeopleOne
(
 [first name] varchar(40) not null,
 [last name]  varchar(40) not null,
 [favorite color] varchar(15) null default 'Willow Blue',
 constraint People_pk primary key ([first name], [last name])
);
```

Comment: What editor are you using?  SSMS?

Comment: So what version ARE you using?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using SSMS, you can use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to refresh the intellisense so you can see the table in the list once you have created it.

Answer (score 1):

If you're referring to Intellisense, you go to Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> Transact-SQL -> Intellisense and enable it.

Comment: thank you. it was enabled. Can you press like the space bar and control to bring it up anywhere like in Java?